# (Greek) what's a "γε causal"?

Tags: greek, meaning, greek-translation, particle

I read in the very beginning of Platon's [Laches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laches_(dialogue)) ([perseus edition](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0175%3Atext%3DLach.%3Asection%3D178a)):

> τεθέασθε μὲν τὸν ἄνδρα μαχόμενον ἐν ὅπλοις, ὦ Νικία τε καὶ Λάχης: οὗ δ᾽ ἕνεκα ὑμᾶς ἐκελεύσαμεν συνθεάσασθαι ἐγώ τε καὶ Μελησίας ὅδε, τότε μὲν οὐκ εἴπομεν, νῦν δ᾽ ἐροῦμεν. ἡγούμεθα γὰρ χρῆναι **πρός γε ὑμᾶς** παρρησιάζεσθαι.

What bothers me is the meaning of **πρός γε ὑμᾶς** I read in [Kenneth Quandt](http://www.onplatoslaches.com/) 's translation:

> Now you have seen the man's display of fighting in armor, Nicias and Laches. Why we asked you to watch it with us, Melesias here and myself, we did not tell you before but now we will, and the reason we will is that we are sure it is right and good to speak openly to **you, given who you are**.

Kenneth Quandt writes about "πρός γε ὑμᾶς" (note 4):

> πρός γε ὑμᾶς, γε causal.

and translates:

> [good to speak openly to] **you, given who you are**

The [particle γε has many meanings](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=ge&la=greek&can=ge0&prior=pro/s&d=Perseus:text:1999.01.0175:text=Lach.:section=178a&i=1#lexicon) and I thought to something simpler, maybe "to speak openly, **especially to you**"(emphasis) or "to speak openly, **at any rate to you**"(restriction).

Anyway, I never heard of a "γε causal" and I don't understand what it could be but Quandt's translation makes sense and sounds interesting. **Do you have any reference explaining such a meaning ?**

Comment: I've never heard of "_ge_ causal" either, and would also translate it as "to you in particular".

Comment: FWIW Denniston's massive *Greek Particles* doesn't seem to recognize a "γε causal" either. That said, in this context it's not too hard to understand what Quandt means: Lysimachus is saying "I wouldn't discuss these things with just anyone, but I will with *you*, because you're the kind of people who would get it", hence Quandt's causal translation "given who you are".

Comment: Its use here seems to be roughly equivalent to quidem in Latin, for what that's worth.

Comment: Isn't this **limitative γε**? - and it *is* in Denniston.

Comment: @AlexB. "limitative γε" is in Denniston, but not "γε causal" unless I'm missing it.

Comment: @TKR I meant to say this “causal” use is better known as limitative.

Comment: @AlexB. Interesting; I hadn't considered those two the same. But that would make a good answer!

Answer (score 2):

*(This answer may not be satisfying, and I'm happy to  have it supplanted in the future! But for now…)*

I've never heard of a "γε causal", nor have any of the classicists I've talked to. A Google search brings up physics papers talking about "gamma-epsilon geodesics", which seem to be something in relativity, but no relevant results about Ancient Greek.

In this case, I took *γε* as intensifying the prepositional phrase: we wouldn't talk to just anyone, but we would definitely talk to *you* (because you're Socrates). This is the same idea Quandt is using in his translation; he's just embellishing a bit more, to make it sound idiomatic in English.

Notably, *γε* has some causal descendants: it's the root of *γάρ*, which could absolutely be called causal. But I've never seen *γε* alone with this meaning.